# Can a proxy server like Cloudflare access all files in server and can read and write them, and if it can how to disable it

Tags: linux, security, proxy, reverse-proxy

How to stop a proxy server from reading, writing files in origin server.

And if I changed name servers of another server and that another server can behave like a proxy and can it access all files like php files and all sensitive code?

Comment: The whole point of the proxy server is to serve your web site!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Does it mean it can access all files and read and write to them, and let's say I use name servers of another server and can it act like a proxy server and access all files and read or write to them and so on?